# Understand JAVA library path argument dynamic creation by JVM

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In general, I am curious how JVM build the list of paths to search when loading libraries (java.library.path)?

In my specific case: We use shared java home in development environment under intellij-idea 11.1.5 (that shared too). The development environments create the list of paths to search not consistently, below 2 possible options (the first one is the desired behavior):

```
java.library.path=/home/shared/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/lib/i386/server:/home/shared/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/lib/i386:/home/shared/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/../lib/i386:/home/shared/jdk/jre/lib/i386/server:/home/shared/jdk/jre/lib/i386:/home/shared/jdk/jre/../lib/i386:.::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib


java.library.path=.::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
```

What can be an explanation for such behaviour? Is it controlled by Intellij?

Comment: Under Windows, the library.path is constructed from the PATH variable accessible to the user i.e. if you are logged in as administrator a different path is visible (more detailed) than if you are logged in as a more restricted user. This path comes to library.path, in Linux also the mechanism would be somewhat similar

Comment: In both cases the user is root.